# Reach third normal form

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbDeletion
  (
     reference       INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     reviewreference INT,
     PersonID        INT,
     EventID         INT,
     [delete]        BIT,
     Deleted         BIT,
     Checked         BIT
  )

INSERT INTO dbdeletion
            (reviewreference,
             personid,
             eventid,
             [delete],
             deleted,
             checked)
VALUES      (1,1,4,0,0,0),
            (2,2,4,1,0,1),
            (3,1,4,1,1,0)
```

I believe this design is in second normal form, but I wanted to check.

The reason I believe it is in second normal form is because of the 'deleted' and 'checked' attributes i.e. every time a record is marked for deletion (dbdeletion.delete=1), then the record is checked to see if it can be deleted.  If it can be deleted, then it is deleted and dbdeletion.deleted is set to 1, else dbdeletion.checked is set to 1.

When dbdeletion.deleted is set to 1 it is set like this:

```
update dbdeletion set deleted=1 where PersonID=@PersonID and EventID=@EventID
```

When dbdeletion.checked is set to 1 it is set like this:

```
update dbdeletion set checked=1 where PersonID=@PersonID and EventID=@EventID
```

The two SQL statements above update 1 or many rows.  Therefore I believe this is not in third normal form.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Let's go through this incrementally.

1. All fields contain one and only one piece of information. **1NF Passed**
2. The primary key is `reference`. `reviewreference` is a candidate key. `PersonID` and `EventID` are not candidate keys because they do not uniquely identify records. Since the candidate keys are atomic, there is no way for another attribute to be dependent on a portion of a candidate key. **2NF Passed**
3. The primary key is `reference` and `reviewreference` is a candidate key. The remaining information all refer to these candidate keys and do not depend on any information aside from these candidate keys. **3NF Passed**

Comment: Thanks. +1 for being thorough. What about 'checked' and 'deleted'. When I want to update either field for a single person,id combination the multiple rows are updated. Should they go in a table on their own?

Comment: The deleted flag and checked flag are held against the personid,eventid.

Comment: Your example above indicated that `deleted` is independent of the non-prime keys. Your first and third records are identical except for `deleted`.

As for `checked`, you might consider that this is dependent on the combination of `PersonID` and `EventID`, but we've established that this combination is not a candidate key for the table. It's also possible that you could add new records to the table with the same combination of `PersonID` and `EventID` with `checked` set to `0` until the check is performed.

Comment: reviewreference is not a candidate key. Firstly because it is nullable and secondly since no uniqueness constraint exists on that column there is no way to infer that is should be a candidate key based on the information supplied.

Comment: @sqlvogel Thank you for catching that. I may have been reading some intent into the structure that wasn't there in the definition.